# Both answer and question are same but he accepts it is right answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

See this question in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486794/phonegap-navigation-bar-not-showing-up#23486968
 both question and answer are same thers is no difference in that anyway he accept the answer.Is that good one.

Comment: There are a few differences, though I cannot reproduce the issue that the OP had.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy see this there is no difference http://jsfiddle.net/ej862/10/ this is the question posted...(i thing you know jquery mobile)

Comment: Generally speaking, bringing attention to the *factual* problems with an answer (i.e. whether or not the answer actually works) isn't something that we do here on the meta site. If you really think the answer is useless/wrong, and you've already pointed it out, just downvote and move on if they won't fix it.

Comment: This is quite a confusing case. OP posted a jQuery code, someone (not OP) commented with jsfiddle to replicate the problem *with different code*, and someone else (not the commenter) answered using the same jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does have a few changes:

- `<div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d">` becomes `<div data-role="navbar">`
- `<a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">` becomes `<a href="#">`.

Just because the differences in code do not appear to change the result does not mean that it should be deleted or flagged as "not an answer" or "very low quality".

If the fact that it has no effect makes the answer not useful, downvote it -- that's what downvotes are for.

If you cannot reproduce the error in the question, go ahead and flag or close the question as off-topic:

> This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

If it becomes clear that the issue is because of something else that is unrelated to the code given, you can also flag or close the question as:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: you know jquery mobile ..check this http://jsfiddle.net/ej862/10/ line number 4 and 5

Comment: I agree with your quoted text(not in top) and strongly disagree with code has changes(in top).and voted to close my question.